# I want to change the image source of a single cell of a table in html

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <tr><!-- 8 -->
            <td id = "8A"><!-- A -->
                <img src="Media/empty_square_white.png" height="160px" width ="160px">
            </td>
    ...
    <script>
        function changeSource(){
        document.getElementById("8A").src="empty_square_brown.png";
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="changeSource">change</button>
```

This is what I have tried to do however when I press the button nothing seems to happen. I have also tried to do this without the button however that didn't seem to work either, I have defined the id using internal CSS as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your id references to the surrounding td which has no attribute src. You need to set the id on the img element or reference to the child element.

Also your new value "empty_square_brown.png" is missing the path which is set in the original source "Media/" and the onclick call needs the function brackets. Here some working example. With a title attribute to show the effect.

```html
<tr><!-- 8 -->
            <td><!-- A -->
                <img id="8A" src="Media/empty_square_white.png" height="160px" width ="160px" title="empty_square_white.png">
            </td>
    ...
    <script>
        function changeSource(){
          document.getElementById("8A").src="Media/empty_square_brown.png";
          document.getElementById("8A").title="empty_square_brown.png";
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="changeSource()">change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```js
function changeImg(){
    document.getElementById("image").src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581618048854-b2f6f877cef3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
}
```

```css
img{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td >
      <img id="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1626285094808-143d7bb02f14?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="" onclick="changeImg()">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="#" alt="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).